# "reduce" function in python not work on "namedtuple"?

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I have a log file that is formatted in the following way:

```
datetimestring \t username \t transactionName \r\n
```

I am attempting to run some stats over this dataset.  I have the following code:

```
import time
import collections
file = open('Log.txt', 'r')

TransactionData = collections.namedtuple('TransactionData', ['transactionDate', 'user', 'transactionName'])
transactions = list()

for line in file:
    fields = line.split('\t')

    transactionDate = time.strptime(fields[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    user = fields[1]
    transactionName = fields[2]

    transdata = TransactionData(transactionDate, user, transactionName)
    transactions.append(transdata)

file.close()

minDate = reduce(lambda x,y: min(x.transactionDate, y.transactionDate), transactions)
print minDate
```

I did not want to define a class for such a simple dataset, so I used a name tuple.  When I attempt to run, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inquiriesStat.py", line 20, in <module>
    minDate = reduce(lambda x,y: min(x.transactionDate, y.transactionDate), transactions)
  File "inquiriesStat.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    minDate = reduce(lambda x,y: min(x.transactionDate, y.transactionDate), transactions)
AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'transactionDate'
```

It appears that the lambda function is operating on the 'transactionDate' property directly instead of passing in the full tuple.  If I change the lambda to:

```
lambda x,y: min(x, y)
```

It works as I would expect.  Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: I believe in a world without `reduce`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use:

```
minDate = min(t.transactionDate for t in transactions)
```

Below is an explanation of why your code isn't working.

Let's say `transactions = [t1, t2, t3]` where `t1`...`t3` are three named tuples.

By the definition of [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce), your code:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: min(x.transactionDate, y.transactionDate), transactions)
```

is equivalent to

```
min(min(t1.transactionDate, t2.transactionDate).transactionDate, t3.transactionDate)
```

Clearly, the inner `min()` returns `time.struct_time` instead of a named tuple, so when `reduce` tries to apply `.transactionDate` to it, that fails.

There are ways to fix this, and to make use of `reduce` for this problem. However, there seems to be little point given that a direct application of `min` does the job and to my eye is a lot clearer than anything involving `reduce`.

Comment: or `key=operator.attrgetter('transactionDate')`. Don't use a `lambda` when there is a built-in that does the same thing.

Comment: reduce doesn't work because the result of the first call (a time.struct_time) to reduce is passed in as one of the arguments to the next call.

Comment: @agf: why, is there a significant difference in efficiency or something that actually makes `operator.attrgetter` preferable?

Comment: contrast with `reduce((lambda x,y: x if x.transactionDate < y.transactionDate else y), transactions)` which would work ;-)

Comment: @Duncan You're right, you'd have to seed it with a `struct_time` to start with, like `transactions[0].transactionDate` or something.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Yes. A call to a function defined in C is much faster than a function defined in Python, and there is one less level of indirection. Plus, why re-implement a built-in? You're not going to do it better / faster than what's already in Python, and you can very easily do it worse, so it's good practice to get used to using the tools provided to you.

Comment: Incompatible return types between function calls to reduce was indeed the problem.  I realize that there are easier built in ways to implement what I have described, but I wanted to see how "map" "reduce" and "lambda" work in python.  Getting back to my lisp roots :)  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @agf: true, I just don't use that effect often enough for its syntax to really stick in my head, and I find it's usually not worth the effort to look it up every time when I could just do the same thing with a lambda function while incurring only a few percent performance penalty. (A test I just ran shows a 4% difference)